# C++ DirectX CreateDevice From Full Window Game

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, handle, directx-9

I am trying to capture a screen from a full screen DirectX game.

I managed to take a screen shot from windowed games but when I try to create a device from a full screen game, it throws an exception.

This is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include "DirectXTools.h"

LPDIRECT3D9 directX;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 directXDevice;

void initDevice(HWND myWindow);
void ConvertCharToWC(char* src, wchar_t* target);

void DirectXTools::CaptureWindow(const char* windowName)
{
    Sleep(5000);
    HWND windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    initDevice(windowHandle);
}

void initDevice(HWND myWindow) {
    D3DDISPLAYMODE  ddm;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS   d3dpp;
    IDirect3DSurface9* g_pSurface;

    if((directX=Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION))==NULL)
    {
        throw "";
    }

    if(FAILED(directX->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,&ddm)))
    {
        throw "";
    }

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp,sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));

    d3dpp.Windowed=FALSE;
    d3dpp.Flags=D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat=ddm.Format;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight=ddm.Height;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth=ddm.Width;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleType=D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    //  d3dpp.SwapEffect=D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect=D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow=myWindow;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval=D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
    d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz=D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;

    if(FAILED(directX->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,myWindow,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING ,&d3dpp,&directXDevice)))
    {
        throw "";
    }

    if(FAILED(directXDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ddm.Width, ddm.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &g_pSurface, NULL)))
    {
        throw "";
    }

    directXDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, g_pSurface);
    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile("temp.bmp",D3DXIFF_BMP,g_pSurface,NULL,NULL);
}
```

The directX->CreateDevice function fails, it doesn't throw an exception but it returns error D3DERR_DEVICELOST.

Anyone has any experience with these kind of thing? maybe I am missing present parameters?

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? Can you include info about what exception is thrown and any details about it when it fails?

Comment: Actually, the directX->CreateDevice method simply fails. The exception that is that empty throw. So technically no exception is throw, the function just fails.

Comment: Have you looked at the return code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to know what is the real problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When an application is fullscreen - only 1 device may be linked to it.
Since a device is already linked to the application (the one who ran the application) our application can't create another device